# Concatenate tag attribute value using Razor and a prefix

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How do I do this in Razor (VB.NET):

```
<div class="some_prefix_@ViewBag.MyValue">
```

If `@ViewBag.MyValue` is "xxx", the output should be

```
<div class="some_prefix_xxx">
```

Comment: What you are doing is corrent, it doesnt work?

Comment: Nope, it just outputs 'some_prefix_@ViewBag.MyValue' :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use parentheses:

```
<div class="some_prefix_@(ViewBag.MyValue)">
```